# Another Encoding/Decoding in C# Issue

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, command-line-interface

I've been working on a GUI for a CLI.  Rather than write everything to a text file, I'm redirecting the standard output, and then creating an abject with the output that I can use/reuse within the GUI code.  I have tried every possible solution I have come across, and I have yet to completely resolve the issue.  It's almost like each line in the return is encoded in 2 different ways.  Here is what I have for the command line interface:

```
class CmdToolInteraction
{

    private static string returnString = null;

    public string runcommandline(string argumentString)
    {
        UnicodeEncoding uni = new UnicodeEncoding();
        Process proc;
        proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = argumentString;

        proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        proc.Start();

        StreamWriter cmdStreamWriter = proc.StandardInput;
        cmdStreamWriter.Write(argumentString);
        cmdStreamWriter.Close();

       returnString = uni.GetString(proc.StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync().Result));

        proc.WaitForExit();

        Console.Write(returnString);
        return returnString;

    }
}
```

Where I'm running into the issue obviously is the output.  Some of it is readable english white the rest is jibberish/Chinese i.e.

`"someone@somewhere.net਍  䰀愀渀最甀愀最攀㨀 攀渀ഀ\n  Success਍ഀ"`

In some instances the entire line or return looks like the second half of the above when I know there should be English alphanumerics instead.

HALP!

**EDIT:**

I updated the code above to add `proc.Startinfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encuding.Unicode`

I still get this string 
 `"someone@somewhere.net਍  䰀愀渀最甀愀最攀㨀 攀渀ഀ\n  Success਍ഀ"` but I know why now.  The second part in this case in BigEndian unicode, whereas the rest was LittleEndian.  Now I'm trying to figure out how the clean the uninterpreted parts.

**Edit #2**
At roelands suggestion I took the unicode output and tried to convert it to ascii.  Similar issue but I feel like I'm getting closer `"someone@somewhere.net਍  䰀愀渀最甀愀最攀㨀 攀渀ഀ\n  Success਍ഀ"` now reads as `"someone@somewhere.net???????????????\n  Success??"`

I have the decoding set to this:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
returnString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: Strange... can you get the result from just "proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync().Result"?

Comment: Are you sure the `CurrentEncoding.GetBytes` is unicode? It may be ASCII, you can't arbitrarily convert one encoding bytes to another encoding without verifying the two are compatible.

Comment: My guess is `StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding` is probably not UTF-16. Your code is massaging a byte stream into a UTF-16 string regardless of the original encoding, hence the gibberish.

Comment: Yeah, StandardOutput is NOT going to be UTF-16 encoded.

Comment: Using Console.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync().Result) after waiting for it to exit causes it to hang.  Debug.Print(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync().Result) gives an empty value.

Comment: Is there a way to  determine what the current output encoding is?

Comment: proc.StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding.WindowsCodePage.ToString() returns 1252..

Comment: Code page 1252 is Windows Latin 1, or ANSI. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc195054.aspx)

Comment: Random chinese characters are often a symptom of interpreting ASCII text as UTF-16. Eg the bytes [65 66] are "AB" as ASCII and "䅂" as UTF-16 (little endian). Try encoding those characters in UTF-16, and then see if those bytes represent ASCII text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's indeed an encoding issue. This is a list of the bytes (part of your string), assuming that string is UTF-16 little endian. Look closely at the bytes around the newline:

```
119 'w'
  0
104 'h'
  0
101 'e'
  0
114 'r'
  0
101 'e'
  0
 46 '.'
  0
110 'n'
  0
101 'e'
  0
116 't'
  0
 13 CR
 10 LF
  0
 32 ' '
  0
 32 ' '
  0
 76 'L'
  0
 97 'a'
  0
110 'n'
  0
103 'g'
  0
117 'u'
  0
```

At some point the UTF-16 byte stream is interpreted as ANSI text, and newlines (`"\n"`) are expanded to CR-LF pairs, corrupting the UTF-16 string.

The solution depends on how your program works. Do you need to run the program via the CMD command processor? If so, do you use the `/U` option? Otherwise, can you open the I/O streams in binary mode?

Comment: Essentially I have a command line tool written by a third party that I use to get information.  So, I don't have access to the source code for the command line tool.  These are the types of results I'm seeing when I run said tool.

Comment: If i have a string `abcdef` and I run `proc.Startinfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode` abc is readable and def with be chinese and jibberish.  if I run `proc.Startinfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode` abc is jibberish/chinese and def is readable in some instances, but not all of them...

Comment: Using the `/U` option seems to do the same thing as `proc.Startinfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a mix-up in your understanding of string and encodings.
The line:

```
returnString = uni.GetString(proc.StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync().Result));
```

Makes absolutely no sense. `proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync().Result` (^) already returns a string. This means the stream of bytes in the console output has already been encoded into a string. The internal representation of strings in .Net happens to be UTF-16 but you should not care what it is. A `string` object is an opaque representation of well, a string. Once you have a string you should not care how it is internally stored. You only need to care about that when you convert it back into a bytes. Then you need to choose how is that string represented (i.e. what encoding to use).

In order to get the output from the cmd process you shoudl just call:

```
returnString = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

If you still get gibberish then the place to look is on the application running inside the command console. My bet is if you run your arguments in an external command console you'll get the same result.

(^) Why do you use `ReadToEndAsync().Result` instead of just `ReadToEnd`?

Comment: Your correct in that the above line is not necessary, now that I have set the `proc.Startinfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode` parameter.  Before, I was getting an ANSI response, which I was (trying) converting to unicode.I was also trying to set it so that is would decode back to unicode regardless of the output encoding, hence the `proc.StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync().Result)` now I am just taking the unicode, converting it to bytes, and then converting back to a unicode string.

Comment: I use `ReadToEndAsync().Result` to  just ensure that I do not run into any blocking issues.

Comment: ReadToEndAsync().Result is functionally the same as ReadToEnd. You need to use wait with a non infinite timeout to prevent blocking issues.